# Is it possible to make a Jython module with Kotlin?

Tags: python, kotlin, jython, python-module, jython-2.7

I want to make a Python/Jython module written in Kotlin.

Kotlin is a Java based language, so I'm wondering if it's possible to use it with Jython. If possible I would like it to be compatible with CPython, the same way Python modules are created with C and Cython. Is it possible to do the same thing with Kotlin and Jython? If not, is it at least possible to make it work only in Jython? I haven't done any research other than a Google search because I don't know where to look.
I'm not sure exactly what I want to make yet, I just want to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to call Kotlin in Jython the same as any Java class/method: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/call-kotlin-from-python-jython/2481